# Help Figuring Out Faulty Proof

Tags: induction, fake-proofs

In my discrete math class, we're working on faulty proofs.
I can't seem to figure out why this proof is faulty. I think it has to due with them assuming $k^2 \le k^2 + 2k$.

Anyone have any ideas?

> $\forall n \in \mathbb N_0 : n^2 \le n.$
>
> *Proof*:
>   Base Case: When $n = 0,\ 0\le 0, \checkmark$.
>   Induction hypothesis: Assume that $k^2 \le k$.
>   Inductive step: Prove $(k + 1)^2 \le k + 1$
>   We work backwards.
>   $$k^2 \le (k + 1)^2 – 1 \le (k + 1) – 1 = k.$$

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:computer-science] and [tag:discrete-mathematics] is inferior to [tag:induction] (From it's tag wiki: _Consider using a more specific tag instead, such as: (...) (induction) (...)_). Please read the tag description before applying a tag

Comment: Sorry my class is named discrete math for computer science, and I didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

"Working backwards" in induction proves the statements *for all smaller numbers* than the base case. You proved
$$k^2 \le k \qquad\forall \mathbb N_0 \ni k \color{red} \le 0$$
The latter set is $\{0\}$ so you only proved the base case and the induction step is invalid.

The reason is you actually assumed $(k+1)^2 \le (k+1)$ and proved $k^2 \le k$ from it, so the step was $k+1\to k$ and not $k\to k+1$.

Answer (score 0):

How do you justify $(k+1)^2 - 1 \leq (k+1) - 1$?

Comment: I think that's them working backwards. It can be rewritten as k^2 ≤ k^2 + 2k <= k. But they assume k^2≤k^2+2k, which is what we're trying to prove, but I don't know.

Comment: Well you are arguing that $k^2 \leq (k+1)^2 - 1$ and that $k^2 \leq k$, but why is $(k+1)^2 - 1 \leq k$?

Comment: The question's purpose was not to critique or request clarification, but to indicate a portion of the 'proof' that was wrong, thus hinting to an answer of the OP's homework question.

Answer (score 0):

'Working backwards' you proved that $$(k + 1)^2 ≤ k + 1 \implies k^2 ≤ k$$ but you have to prove that  $$k^2 ≤ k \implies (k + 1)^2 ≤ k + 1$$